# Persist login on Firebase with Google Sign-in?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I'm currently using Firebase such that users sign in with their Google accounts to access the app. However, closing the page/opening the page in a new tab requires the user to sign in again. Is there a way to prevent users from having to re-login?

Here is the login code I am using (the example from the firebase docs)

```
function firebaseLogin() {
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    var user = result.user;
    document.getElementById('user-name').innerHTML = user.displayName;
    document.getElementById('propic').src = user.photoURL;
    addClass(login, 'hidden');
    removeClass(logout, 'hidden');
    var snackbarData = {
      message: 'Login Successful',
      timeout: 2000
    };
    snackbarContainer.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(snackbarData);
    console.log(user);
    reloadList();
  }).catch(function(error) {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    var email = error.email;
    var credential = error.credential;
    var snackbarData = {
      message: 'Login Unsuccessful',
      timeout: 2000
    };
    snackbarContainer.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(snackbarData);
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it is impossible to say why your app is behaving the way it does.

Comment: Please specify the environment you are using. Also make sure you are using an auth state observer to check the current auth state. Checking firebase.auth().currentUser synchronously on load will not return the current logged in user (state determination is an async operation). Some developers make this mistake.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I'll switch to using an auth state observer when I come back to this project. As for the environment, this is a web project, using just javascript in the browser (clientside).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the official way to do it, but I ended up saving the user returned from `firebase.auth().currentUser` in localStorage, and then checking if a user could be found in localStorage on document load. If a user is found, I just set firebase.auth().currentUser to equal the user from localStorage, and everything seemed to work as intended. (For example, if there wasn't an authenticated user, the client wouldn't be able to make calls to the database, but setting currentUser in this fashion allowed accessing the database.)

Comment: I used a similar approach as described, however, I get the message 'Error: "currentUser" is read-only"

Comment: Hmm, I haven't run into that. Then again, I haven't tested this application again since the 3rd, so perhaps there was a change in Firebase?