# How can I persist my Google login with Firebase? - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
<body>
  <div id="user-id-container"></div>
  <button id="logout-button" style="display:none">Logout</button>
  <button id="google-login-button">Sign in with Google</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      // Handle the Google login button click event
      $('#google-login-button').click(function () {
        firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
          .then(function () {
            return firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
          })
          .then(function (result) {
            // Display the user ID on the screen
            $('#user-id-container').text(result.user.email);
            // Hide the login button and show the logout button
            $('#google-login-button').hide();
            $('#logout-button').show();
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            // Handle errors
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            alert(errorMessage);
          });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

I am a beginner in JavaScript and studying.
I want to keep the login, but if I press Refresh, the login will not be maintained.
How can I maintain my login?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557355/persist-login-on-firebase-with-google-sign-in

Answer (score 0):

On most browser-based environments Firebase Authentication automatically persists the credentials and restores them when the app/page reloads, so you shouldn't have to call `setPersistence`.

Restoring the credentials requires that the Firebase SDK makes a call to the server (a.o. to check if the account was suspended), which won't be done by the time your on-page-load JavaScript run. To pick up the restored authentication state, register an `onAuthStateChanged` listener as shown in the first code sample in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).